# OWASP ZAP full scan stopped working in CICD pipeline

Tags: azure, owasp, zap, cicd

I have been experimenting with running ZAP in an Azure CI pipeline and it's been going fine until today; I was running the pipeline and right when it got to running the zap full scan, it froze. I stopped getting an output and the pipeline ended up timing out. At first I thought it was because I changed something in the .yml file, but even after I reverted the changes the pipeline didn't run successfully. Does anyone know what might be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide some screenshots, the content of the yaml, or anything else that can provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

We've just released ZAP 2.11.0 - if you are using the docker image then you will probably have picked up the new version. We're not aware of any problems but that doesnt mean there aren't any. We have a FAQ on where to start looking if you have problems with ZAP: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/